# Upload custom thumbnail to JW player video Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, customization, jwplayer

Is there any way to add a custom thumbnail for the video in the JW player in Laravel?

I am trying to add a custom create thumbnail add in the JW player instead their own created.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to upload a video thumbnail to the JW player video.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for the `image` option in the player configuration:
https://docs.jwplayer.com/players/reference/setup-options#media.

Note: "Thumbnail" is called "poster" in JWPlayer.